# Convert 201507 into 07/01/2015 (MM/DD/YYYY) in vectorwise

Tags: function, date, datetime

I need to Convert 201507 into 07/01/2015 (MM/DD/YYYY) without using datetime function.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Why not try building it using the substring function?
     SUBSTR(str, position [, substring_length ])